# How to calculate the probability of a large number to be divisible by a prime number?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, prime-numbers

For example, $\frac{23023}{23}=1001, \mod 0$. 
Let's say I want to encode my book with number $23$ as my pattern that shows the intactness of my book in any new print. I also do not declare this but let's say I also mentioned the number $23$ out of context in my book for curious readers. 
If someone realise years later that the number of all the letters in my book is divisible by $23$.

How likely s/he can can think of this can occur by chance?

What is the general way of calculating this for any other prime number?

Comment: I think where you wrote "mod $0$" you meant remainder $0$; i.e., $23023\equiv0\mod23$

Comment: yes, that is correct, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [natural density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density) of multiples of $n$, whether $n$ is prime or not, is $\frac 1n$.  This would be the justification for saying that $\frac 1n$ of all numbers are divisible by $n$.

Answer (score 1):

If you divide $a$ by $b$, there are $b$ possible values of the remainder. If all of those remainders are equally likely, then there is probability $\frac 1 b$ that the remainder will be zero, i.e. $a$ is divisible by $b$. Whether $b$ is a prime is not relevant.